# Create a new service in Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I have an Amazon ec2 instance running Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03. I would like to create a startup service but I can't use systemctl as I'm not on Amazon Linux 2.

The service is a Python script that I would like to run at startup and be able to start/stop. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux 1 is using `sysvinit` system, unlike `systemd` in Amazon Linux 2. One way of setting it up to manage your service is shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490201/how-do-i-configure-my-amazon-linux-service-to-auto-restart-if-it-fails).

However, Amazon Linux 1 has only **few months left of its lifetime**:

- [Update on Amazon Linux AMI end-of-life](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/update-on-amazon-linux-ami-end-of-life/)

Thus if you can, please consider using Amazon Linux 2. Sooner or later you will have to switch to AL2 anyway for security reasons, so may try doing this now.